# Bitmap not showing (QR code Xzing)

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I try to show a QR code was generated by a url. But the bitmap not showing.
What is the solution for this.
I use `xzing` library:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

My `activity`:

```
public class QRCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int WIDTH = 256;
private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;
private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;

@BindView(R.id.qrcode_toolbar)
Toolbar _toolBar;
@BindView(R.id.generate_code_button)
Button _generate_code_button;
@BindView(R.id.qrCode_imageView)
ImageView _qrCode_imageView;

Bitmap qrcode;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        qrcode = encodeAsBitmap("aadeaokode");
        _qrCode_imageView.setImageBitmap(qrcode);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrcode);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str,
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, WIDTH, WIDTH, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int w = result.getWidth();
    int h = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        int offset = y * w;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, WIDTH, 0, 0, w, h);
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

Comment: try to put setImageBitmap after setContentView()

Comment: thanks for response, but i found the problem because `AppCompatButton`   overlay `AppCompatImageView`